# Failed to find user 'avahi'

Tags: cups, avahi

So I'm trying to setup CUPS + AirPrint support and one of the packages required is Avahi.

I have installed it via ipkg, and have tried running the daemon, however I get the following error.

```
Failed to find user 'avahi'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By creating a user "avahi".

```
adduser --system --shell /bin/false --home /var/run/avahi --disabled-password avahi
```